# How to disallow taking the address of an object

Tags: c++

I'm playing around with a small class `Foo` and am considering writing `register Foo foo;`.

I know that for `register` to actually work, you can't take the address of `foo`.

But that is not enforced on compilation. Is there any way I can forbid taking `&foo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If want to disable the address of operator then you could write

`Foo* operator&() = delete;`

in you class declaration for `Foo`.

But there's a bit or irony here: you can only do that in C++11 onwards and `register` is deprecated in those standards! It's only a partial solution anyhow: you can still use `std::addressof`, or even reference-cast to `char&` and take the address of that.

Prior to C++11, you *could* declare your own version of `operator&`, mark it `private`, and *not* implement it. Compilation will fail most of the time (unless you use `&` in a method of the class), and link-time will always fail. But this can still be circumvented with a reference-cast to `char&`.

Comment: Note that `register` is deprecated.

Comment: Ha. That's a good point. I've attempted to salvage some dignity here.

Comment: I'd clear up the wording here by saying "declare it private, and then not implement it." The way it's currently written implies an implementation.

Comment: @AndyG: thank you, so now my comment applies to you too.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you like totally rewrote this answer, I guess it's right.

Comment: you'll want to specialise std::addressof<> for the class too.